# validate username with regex in javascript

Tags: javascript, regex

I am a newbie to regex and would like to create a regular expression to check usernames. **These are the conditions:**

1. username must have between 4 and 20 characters
2. username must not contain anything but letters a-z, digits 0-9 and special characters -._
3. the special characters -._ must not be used successively in order to avoid confusion
4. the username must not contain whitespaces

**Examples**

- *any.user.13* => valid
- *any..user13* => invalid (two dots successively)
- *anyuser* => valid
- *any* => invalid (too short)
- *anyuserthathasasupersuperlonglongname* => invalid (too many characters)
- *any username* => invalid because of the whitespace

**I've tried to create** my own regex and only got to the point where I specify the allowed characters:

```
[a-z0-9.-_]{4,20}
```

Unfortunately, it still matches a string if there's a whitespace in between and it's possible to have two special chars .-_ successively:

[image: matches although whitespace and two dots successively]

If anybody would be able to provide me with help on this issue, I would be extremely grateful. Please keep in mind that I'm a newbie on regex and still learning it. Therefore, an explanation of your regex would be great.

Thanks in advance :)

Comment: It is easiest if you provide a list of rules that you test against one by one. By using that approach, you can let the user know which rule (s)he has violated.

Comment: Well I‘ve opted for an approach that shows the user a message which specifies what could be the reason why the username is invalid. Using ifs for such checks is tedious...

Comment: Serious question: why are you putting all these restrictions on user names? Other than perhaps max length (which because of varchar should also not particularly matter), what _real_ reasons do you have for all these restrictions? (e.g. your code for _displaying_ user names shouldn't care. It might cut off usernames, but you should simply tell people that when they sign up. "picking a long username means people won't see the whole thing")

Comment: @Mike'Pomax'Kamermans because it's common practice to do so. For example, depending on the used font, users couldn't recognize that my__username has two underlines. Also, these rules prevent users from creating usernames like _________name________

Comment: "Other people do it" is not a real reason. Tons of sites do this and it's a pain the ass as a user =) If someone wants the username `__` then as long as your front end is clear about what is a username and what isn't, there is nothing wrong with that username, and it is important to remember that. Wanting to restrict it is fine, but a lot of "common practice" is based on technical limitations from decades ago, effectively none of which still apply if you're writing something new.

Comment: @Mike'Pomax'Kamermans I know what you mean, but in my case the usernames should be restricted. Usernames should be easy to read for humans, and a username of ____ just isn't easy to read, if you know what I mean.

Comment: fair enough, but then I'd still recommend not putting in the articial "a-z" and instead at the very least allow all printable unicode, with a normal validator (that someone else already wrong, no need to reinvent your own, just grab a validator off the virtual shelf)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Sometimes writing a regular expression can be almost as challenging as finding a user name. But here you were quite close to make it work. I can point out three reasons why your attempt fails.

First of all, we need to match all of the input string, not just a part of it, because we don't want to ignore things like white spaces and other characters that appear in the input. For that, one will typically use the anchors `^` (match start) and `$` (match end) respectively.

Another point is that we need to prevent two special characters to appear next to each other. This is best done with a negative lookahead.

Finally, I can see that the tool you are using to test your regex is adding the flags `gmi`, which is not what we want. Particularly, the `i` flag says that the regex should be case insensitive, so it should match capital letters like small ones. Remove that flag.

The final regex looks like this:

`/^([a-z0-9]|[-._](?![-._])){4,20}$/`

There is nothing really cryptic here, except maybe for the group `[-._](?![-._])` which means any of `-._` not followed by any of `-._`.

Comment: Thanks a lot for this answer :) I almost guessed that I should use negative lookahead but didn’t know how to achieve it 

Comment: I have been searching for the last 2 hours, you have saved my time. - Thanks a lot buddy @GOTO 0